# Parser Changing the Base64 Encoded String

Tags: android, encoding

I am trying to upload a picture to a MySQLi server. To do so I made a table with the columns id which is an int and the image which is a LongBlob.
I used the method:

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, baos);
 byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
 String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

To encode the image and:

```
byte[] image;
image= Base64.decode(imageString,Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
```

To decode it. The problem is that I get this error:

```
decoder->decode returned false
```

I have noticed after a lot of checking that the parser changes the string that I uploaded.

This is the parser:

```
public class JSONParser {

static JSONObject jObj;
static String json;

// constructor
public JSONParser() {
}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public static JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, ContentValues params) {
    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request;
        // check for request method
        if (method.equals("POST")) {
            // request method is POST

            MediaType contentType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
            String content = "";
            for (String key : params.keySet())
            {
                if ( !content.isEmpty())
                    content += "&";

                content += key + "=" + params.get(key);
            }

            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(contentType, content);
            request = new Request.Builder().url(url).post(body).build();
        }
        else  {
            // request method is GET
            request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
        }
        final Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        json = response.body().string();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e ){
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}
}
```

How do I change the parser so that the string will remain as the original?

Comment: Your encoding en decoding is ok. So something goes wrong -sending it to the server -putting it in the database -extracting from database -downloading to Android.

Comment: Please do not add links to external sites, especially to ones that try to open ad windows.

Comment: Sorry for the ads, I only wanted to show the picture itself, I have also written the the code to a file and compared to the one on the server, nothing went wrong while uploading from a quick glance. When I will get home I will post the parser that uploads it if it helps. Although maybe the parser chages some of the signs to other signs.